# Automate Acrobat Compare Files Tool

Tags: acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to launch the Acrobat DC Compare Files tool with PDFs specified, either through the API or JavaScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The best you'll be able to do is customize the toolbar so that the compare feature is always available and then command line launch Acrobat twice to get the two files open then click the compare tool.